# How to add characters from a file that are not evenly spaced?

Tags: c++

I'm taking C++ for the first time. And I'm a bit stuck on the final entry calculation.
5+6- 7 -8 + 9  + 10 -   11;

The question deliberately spaces things out of order and I don't know how to account for it. Any help on this would be amazing as I don't know what I'm missing. Thank you so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int val;

  while (cin >> val)
  {
    string op;

    while (cin >> op)
    {
      if (op == ";")
      {
        cout << val << endl;
        break;
      }
      
      

      int num;

      if (! (cin >> num)) {
        cout << "a number is expected after '" << op << '\'' << endl;
        return -1;
      }
      

      if (op == "+")
      {
        val += num;
      }
      else if (op == "-")
      {
        val -= num; 
      }
      else {
        cout <<"invalid operator '" << op << '\'' << endl;
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `op` to `char` instead of `string`.

Comment: What does "add characters from a file" mean? What does "evenly spaced" mean? This question is unclear, and it's not explained exactly what the shown code has to do with the question. Try to pretend that you're talking to a busy colleague, and need to explain your question in the fewest words possible. Now, what is your question about the C++ programming language? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Thanks @JohnFilleau - when I replace ```spring op``` for ```char op``` --> I get this error though C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.

Comment: @Omar you also need to change every comparison between `op` and string literals (things between `" "` like `"+"`) with a comparison to `char`s instead (things between `' '` like `'+'`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here and this is my first attempt at answering a question. This might not be the best way to do it.
I think you should read the whole thing in a string with getline(cin, string), then go through the string with a for loop and get rid of all spaces. Then you can define a string stream from the resulting string and use it instead of cin.
It will look something like this:

```
    string s1,s2;
    getline(cin, s1);
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (s1[i] != ' ')
            s2 += s1[i];
    }
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s2;
```

and from now on use ss instead of cin.
just make sure to include sstream and string headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/0lWhCE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val;
    int num;
    char op;
    bool isNotStop(true);
    cin>>val;
    while (isNotStop)
    {
        cin.get(op);
        //cout<<"Craracter is: ["<<op << "]"<<endl;
        if(isspace(op)) continue;
        
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                if (!(cin >> num))
                {
                    cout << "a number is expected after '" << op << '\'' << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                val += num;
                break;
                
            case '-':
                if (!(cin >> num))
                {
                    cout << "a number is expected after '" << op << '\'' << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                val -= num;
                break;
                break;
            
            case ';':
                isNotStop = false;
                break;
                
            default:
                {
                    cout <<"invalid operator '" << op << '\'' << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Result: "<<val;
    return 0;
}
```